# Private VLANs on a switch that doesn't support Private VLAN trunks

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

I have a Catalyst switch that doesn't support PVLAN trunks (Sup4, 4500, 12.2(54)S).  I have multiple other Catalyst switches, 3750 metro, that do.

Am I correct in assuming that because the C4500 does not support PVLAN trunks with that Supervisor, that a normal trunk port would not work for the 3750s to share a private VLAN with the 4500?

The desired scenario is that the 4500 hosts primary VLAN 500 and isolated vlans 501,502 with 501,502 residing on other 3750s in the network.  I assume that in order to achieve the desired config, I have to have the 3750 promiscuous ports connected to access ports on the 4500.  Is this correct?

[image: Example image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **promiscuous trunk** on the 3750 toward the 4500 is what you need to go across a non-PVLAN-aware switch and keep security intact.

See [Promiscuous PVLAN Trunk Ports](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12.2/54sg/configuration/guide/pvlans.html#wp1181949)

Comment: The 4500 is PVLAN-aware.  I assume what "no PVLAN trunks" means is that the promiscuous and isolated special-type trunks aren't available.  I'm looking for verification.